# UIActivityIndicator in NavigationItem slow to appear

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using a `UIActivityIndicator` inside a `UIBarButtonItem` to show activity, but the indicator is slow to appear. I'm creating it using

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *innerActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[innerActivityIndicator startAnimating];
self.activityIndicator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:innerActivityIndicator];
```

Then toggling visibility using

```
if(loading){
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:activityIndicator animated:true];
} else {
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:true];
}
```

Generally it takes 4 or 5 seconds before it actually appears and I have no idea why. I was originally starting/stopping the animation but this also did not work. I've had this problem/effect in two apps now so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there a chance that you're accidentally doing this in a background thread?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Of course that would cause a slow response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Adams pointed out, the problem was I was adding and removing the indicator from a background thread using GCD.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constantly adding and removing the indicator, consider simply hiding it when you don't want it to appear. You can either do this by setting `hidden` to `YES` and `NO`, or, preferably, set the `hidesWhenStopped` to `YES` and then do

```
if(loading){
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
} else {
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

One tip is to start the activityIndicator spinning ***before*** doing whatever action will take a while, and stop it after the action has completed. If you start an intensive action before starting the activityIndicator, that might explain the lag time.

Comment: I've tried that, but I did say that in the question. I see the same effect.

Comment: @Echilon When you write that it takes 4 or 5 seconds, how are you measuring this? Did you drop an `NSlog` into the `if` statement?

Comment: No, I'm just watching it appear. Sometimes the request takes longer than other times, I've also tried adding an `NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:` into the call to load data. I'm doing the actual work on a background thread using GCD.